# Get simple JSON from PHP and use as Backbone collection?

Tags: php, ajax, json, backbone.js

I have searched around and have found far more complicated examples than what I need to do.

I have a PHP page (data.php) which queries a MYSQL database and returns JSON of 3 employees.

In the code below, I have hard-coded an example of the returned JSON and the whole thing works as expected.

What I'd like to find out is what is the simplest way to replace the hard-coded JSON below with JSON fetched from data.php on load.

```
// Model
Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults: {
    first_name: 'John',
    last_name: 'Doe',
    department: 'Corporate',
    title: 'Admin'
}
});

// List of People
var PeopleCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: Person
});

var PeopleView = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName: 'ul',

render: function(){
    this.collection.each(function(person){
        var personView = new PersonView({model: person});
        this.$el.append(personView.render().el);
    }, this);
    return this;
}
});

// The View for a Single Person
var PersonView = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName: 'li',

template: _.template( $('#personTemplate').html() ),

render: function() {
    this.$el.html( this.template(this.model.toJSON()) );
    return this;
}
});

var peopleCollection = new PeopleCollection(

[{"first_name":"Jodie","last_name":"Smith","short_name":"SmithJ","department":"Creative","phone":"3446","start_date":"0000-00-00","end_date":"0000-00-00","active":"1","title":"Web Design Director","id":"492"},{"first_name":"Michael","last_name":"Johnson","short_name":"JohnsonM","department":"Interactive","phone":"3761","start_date":"0000-00-00","end_date":"0000-00-00","active":"1","title":"Sr. Director, Interactive","id":"569"},{"first_name":"Frank","last_name":"Thomas","short_name":"ThomasF","department":"Distribution","phone":"3516","start_date":"0000-00-00","end_date":"0000-00-00","active":"1","title":"Warehouse Coordinator","id":"454"}]

);

var peopleView = new PeopleView({ collection: peopleCollection });
$(document.body).append(peopleView.render().el)
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has JSON built in:
[see PHP JSON Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Answer (score 0):

I hevent used backbone much so i cant comment on how to make the request to data.php but im assuming you know how to do that part... so i will focus on the contents of data.php

```
$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM people');
$stmt->execute();

$people = array();

while(false !== ($person = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))) {
  // if you need to do any manipulation to the person structure you would do it here
  // before assigning it to people.
  $people[] = $person; 
}

// prepare our response; json_encode turns our PHP Hash into a JSON string
$response = json_encode(array(
   'total' => count($people), // this will be a Number
   'people' => $people, // this will be a []
   // whatever else you might need from the server side
));

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo $response;
exit;
```

This would then give you something like:

```
{"total":0,"people":[]}
```

So you would use:

```
var peopleCollection = new PeopleCollection(theAjaxResponse.people);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I created my peopleCollection inside the initialize method of the view, and then inside the PeopleCollection object added the url property. See:

```
// Person Model
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults: {
    first_name: 'John',
    last_name: 'Doe',
    department: 'Corporate',
    title: 'worker'
}
});

// A List of People
var PeopleCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: Person,
url: '/hr/data.php'

});

// view for all people
var PeopleView = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName: 'ul',

initialize: function() {
        this.collection = new PeopleCollection();
        this.collection.bind("reset", this.render, this);
        this.collection.fetch();
    },

render: function(){
    this.collection.each(function(person){
        var personView = new PersonView({model: person});
        this.$el.append(personView.render().el);
    }, this);
    return this;
}
});

// The View for a Person
var PersonView = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName: 'li',

template: _.template( $('#personTemplate').html() ),

render: function() {
    this.$el.html( this.template(this.model.toJSON()) );
    return this;
}
 });

 var peopleView = new PeopleView();
 $(document.body).append(peopleView.render().el)
```